# spring boot, cloud spring config error , why isn't this working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I want to build cloud configuration and I have this message when I compile the java class   :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : 
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:251)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at org.so.ServiceConfigApplication.main(ServiceConfigApplication.java:12)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/origin/OriginLookup
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:408)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.origin.OriginLookup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more
```

Code

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>

        </parent>
        <groupId>org.rem</groupId>
        <artifactId>service_config</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>service_config</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>




    <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud-services.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                 <version>8.5.11</version>

            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    </project>
```

Comment: I think thi is happening because of spring version ` <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>`. Try upgrading spring version

Comment: @AvijitBarua  I have this now : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean

Comment: Can you remove version from `<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>` this dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and have solved it! I did this by removing the following configuration from my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
     <version>xxxx</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi yasmina_rmc please add spring-web dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```